# How to send a message to google hangouts with python?

Tags: google-api, google-hangouts

I am trying to create a simple "chat bot" for google hangouts that sends regular messages on a chat. I found [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/service-accounts) but I find it tremendously complicated.

It contains a "Complete example" but I am not sure about how to find the "space" ID for an existing google hangout chat. This is nowhere explained. How do I find the "space" ID for an existing google chat?

And in addition: Is there a **SIMPLE** (!!!) documentation somewhere how to just simply post a message to an existing chat?

Comment: Programmatically, or at all?

Comment: Programmatically, i.e. with a python script. It should run periodically (cronjob) to send information to the chat

Comment: Why do you need the space ID? The bot should be able to respond directly in the room in which it was messaged/pinged without specifying the space ID

Comment: The space ID is required in the example on the page I referenced.

Comment: Also, the bot is not supposed to "respond". The "bot" is only supposed to SEND a message. Only sending a message, no receiving, no responding

Answer (score 7):

#### Answer:

*You can either use [`spaces.list`](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces/list) to get a list of spaces the bot is a member of followed by [`spaces.get`](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces/get) for additional information on the space, or alternatively set up a room-specific Webhook.*

#### Additional Information:

- To send messages to a room without a respond trigger, you must use a [service account](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/service-accounts)
- Bot-initiated message documentation can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/bots-develop#bot-initiated_messages).

***Important Note:*** *You can only use the Google Hangouts Chat API if you have a Google Workspace account - it will not work with Gmail alone. The second solution, which uses a Webhook, requires access to https://chat.google.com which is only available to Google Workspace domains. Unfortunately this is not at all possible using a consumer `@gmail.com` account.*

#### Using the Hangouts Chat API:

Once you have a service account set up [as per Step 1 on this page](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/service-accounts#step_1_create_service_account_and_private_key), you can download the credentials for the service account from the Google Cloud Project UI, by clicking on the `⋮` button to the right of the service account name, and following the `Create key` button and selecting JSON as the key type. **Make sure to save this file well as there is only one copy of this key.**

With this JSON file downloaded, you can use it in your python code as the credentials when setting up your service object:

```py
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from apiclient.discovery import build

scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat.bot'
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
    'credentials.json', scopes)

chat_service = build('chat', 'v1', http=credentials.authorize(Http()))
```

To make the `spaces.list` request, you can use this newly built `chat_service`, and extract hte list of spaces from the response:

```py
def extract(n):
    return n['name']

spaces_list = chat_service.spaces().list().execute()
all_spaces = map(extract, spaces_list['spaces'])
```

You can then use one of these spaces to send a message from the python program:

```py
response = chat_service.spaces().messages().create(
    parent=all_spaces[0],
    body={'text': 'Test message'}).execute()
print(response)
```

#### Things to Remember:

- Make sure the Hangouts Chat API is enabled for your project at https://console.cloud.google.com
- Once enabled, make sure the bot is configured with a name, logo and description.
- The Connection settings for the bot must also be set up; the method is not so important; you can for example choose `Apps Script project` and enter the deployment ID for an empty deployed project.

#### Using a Webhook:

Instead of directly using the API, you can instead set up a webhook for a specific chat and with a hardcoded URL, you can send messages to a room from an external script.

The full steps are set out on [this page](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/quickstart/incoming-bot-python) but I'll go through it here also.

Go to the room to which you wish to send a message at https://chat.google.com, and from the dropdown menu next to the room's name, select `Manage Webhooks`.

Enter a name and an optional avatar for your bot, and press `SAVE`. This will give you a webhook URL to use in your python script.

Locally, make sure you have `httplib2` installed in your environment, and copy the following script into a new `.py` file:

```py
from json import dumps
from httplib2 import Http

def main():
    """Hangouts Chat incoming webhook quickstart."""
    url = 'webhook-url'
    bot_message = {
        'text' : 'Hello from a Python script!'}

    message_headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}

    http_obj = Http()

    response = http_obj.request(
        uri=url,
        method='POST',
        headers=message_headers,
        body=dumps(bot_message),
    )

    print(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Manking sure to replace the `webhook-url` string with the webhook provided in the Chat UI in the previous step.

Now you can just save the file and run it - this will send a message automatically to the aforementioned chat space:

[image]

#### References:

- [Creating new bots | Google Chat API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/bots-develop#bot-initiated_messages)
- [Method: spaces.list | Google Chat API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces/list)
- [Method: spaces.get | Google Chat API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces/get)
- [REST Resource: spaces | Google Chat API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces)

Comment: How do I make a call to `spaces.list`? Do I just use `requests`? Or something else? There is unfortunately no example given how to do it programatically, and I am not an google API expert...

Comment: In addition, I get an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apiclient.discovery'` when I try to create one of the examples after I did `pip install apiclient`. Maybe I did install the wrong `apiclient`? There is NOTHING about that on the google documentation pages.

Comment: @Alex Make a `spaces.list` call by making an HTTP GET request to `https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces`. You don't need to provide a request body just your auth credentials. Also check out the Incoming webhook guide [here](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/quickstart/incoming-bot-python) as that might be better for your needs.

Comment: What are my auth credentials? Where exactly can I find them? Can you provide a complete example of such a GET call?

Comment: @Alex Let's have a [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227515/room-for-rafa-guillermo-and-alex) :)

Comment: Thanks for the webhook suggestion, but the dropdown menu does not have an entry "Manage Webhooks". So that solution also does not seem to work.

Comment: Ah, this is only for Google Chat at [https://chat.google.com](https://chat.google.com) not [https://hangouts.google.com/](https://hangouts.google.com)... unfortunately, this is not possible for consumer Gmail accounts either.

Comment: @RafaGuillermo Thanks, above solution worked for me. Is it possible to upload and download files to google chat?

Comment: @SwapnilPandit I suggest asking a new question to tackle this :)

Answer (score -1):

See this API, it's very interesting:
https://pypi.org/project/hangups/

There is some projects who uses Hangups, among then, HangupsBot:
https://github.com/xmikos/hangupsbot

Comment: Thanks for this package, but it does not seem to work. I am unable to login `Login failed (Failed to find form '#gaia_loginform' in page)`